# Vue link computed function to disable textboxes where there is no value

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Hi I have a vue template and component built. I want to use the disableEmailText under computed Vue to disable the textboxes if user has no value. I am not sure how to link the disableEmailText function to the commands component I built. Can someone maybe help out, please?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div v-for="(commands, groupName) in groupedCommands">
      <h4>@{{ groupName }}</h4>
      <div class="btn-group" v-for="command in commands">
        <commands-component
                :entity-config="commandConfig(command.id, command.signature, command.user, command.title, command.groupID, command.groupName)">
                <input style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:value="command.title">
        </commands-component>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Vue:

```
    var systemadmin = new Vue({
    el: "#sysadmin",
    data: function() {
        return {
          users: <?php echo $users ?>,
          commands: <?php echo $commands ?>,
        }
    },
    created: function() {

    },
    updated: function() {

    },
    computed: {
      groupedCommands: function(){
          return this.commands.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.groupName] = r[a.groupName] || [];
            r[a.groupName].push(a);
            return r;
          }, Object.create(null));
        },

        disableEmailText: function(user){
          if (user == ''){
            document.getElementsByName("emailText").disabled = true;
          }
        }

    },
    methods: {

        commandConfig: function(ident, signature, user, title, groupId, groupName){
            $data = {

                id: { text: 'commandModal' + ident, id: null },
                modalTitle: title,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        buttonTitle: 'Run Command',
                        buttonClass: 'btn btn-success pull-right',
                        submitUrl: {
                            url: '/admin/artisan/commands/run',

                        },
                    }
                ],
                attributes: [
                {name: "message", displayName: "Are you sure you want to proceed with the command?", type: "action-text",  col: "12" },
                {name: "signature", displayName: "Command Signature", type:'text', col:"6"},
                {name: 'emailText', displayName: "Email", type: 'text', col: '6'}
                ],
                data: {
                    signature:signature,

                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: I added the components code:

```
    <script type="text/x-template" id="commands-template">
<span>
    <span v-on:click="showModal">
        <slot></slot>
    </span>
    <div class="modal fade top-left" v-bind:id="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@{{ entityConfig.modalTitle }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="submitItem">
                        <meta id="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div v-for="attr in entityConfig.attributes" style="min-height:70px;" v-bind:class="'col-md-' + (attr.col == undefined ? 12 : attr.col)">
                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'display'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <input disabled type="text" v-bind:name="attr.name" class="form-control" v-model="computedData[attr.name]" />
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'text'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <input type="text" v-bind:name="attr.name" class="form-control" v-model="computedData[attr.name]" />
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'textarea'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <textarea v-bind:name="attr.name" class="form-control" rows=3 v-model="computedData[attr.name]"></textarea>
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'checkbox'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" v-bind:name="attr.name" class="form-control"  v-model="computedData[attr.name]" />
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'date'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <input v-bind:id="id + '-pikaday'" class="form-control"
                                        v-bind:name="attr.name" v-pikaday="computedData[attr.name]" type="text" v-model="computedData[attr.name]"/>
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'file'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label class="input-group-btn">
                                            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                                                Browse&hellip;<input type="file" style="display: none;" v-on:change="fileChange(attr, $event)">
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled v-bind:value="computedData[attr.name]">
                                    </div>
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'select'">
                                    <label v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}:</label>
                                    <select v-model="computedData[attr.name]" class="form-control sel-md sel-primary">
                                        <option v-for="option in attr.options" v-bind:value="option.value">
                                            @{{ option.text }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </template>

                                <template v-if="attr.type == 'action-text'">
                                    <h3 class="text-center"  v-bind:for="attr.name">@{{ attr.displayName }}</h3>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row top-buffer">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" v-for="error in formErrors">
                                    @{{ error.error }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" v-if="processing">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="cssload-container">
                                    <div class="cssload-loading">
                                        <i></i>
                                        <i></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row top-buffer" v-if="entityConfig.message">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div v-bind:class="'alert alert-' + entityConfig.message.type" >
                                    @{{ entityConfig.message.message }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div style="padding:15px;">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" v-on:click="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div style="padding:15px;">
                                    <span v-for="button in entityConfig.buttons">
                                        <button type="submit" v-bind:class="button.buttonClass" style="margin-right:20px !important;"
                                            v-on:click.prevent="submitItem(button)" v-bind:disabled="processing">
                                            @{{ button.buttonTitle }}
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

AND:

```
    Vue.component('commands-component', {
    template: '#commands-template',
    // replace: true,
    twoWay: true,
    props: {
        entityConfig: Object,
        entityData: Object
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            show: false,
            processing: false,
            defaultData: {},
            formErrors: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        var data = this.entityConfig.data;
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.defaultData[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedData: function() {
            if (this.entityData != undefined) {
                return this.entityData;
            } else {
                return this.entityConfig.data;
            }
        },
        id: function() {
            var id = this.entityConfig.id.text;

            if (this.entityConfig.id.id) {
                id = id + '-' + this.computedData[this.entityConfig.id.id];
            }

            return id;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitItem: function(button) {
            this.processing = true;

            var that = this;
            var submitData = this.computedData;
            var request = getFormData(submitData);

            var url = button.submitUrl.url;
            if (button.submitUrl.id) {
                url = url + submitData[button.submitUrl.id]
            }

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("#_token").attr("content")
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: request,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    that.formErrors = [];
                    that.$emit('submitted', response);
                    that.processing = false;
                    that.closeModal();
                    that.entityConfig.data = that.defaultData;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    that.formErrors = [];
                    if (error.status == 422) {
                        console.log( error.responseJSON);
                        for (var key in error.responseJSON.errors) {
                            console.log(key);
                            if (error.responseJSON.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                that.formErrors.push({ error: error.responseJSON.errors[key][0] });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    toastr.error(getHTTPStatusCodeMessage(error.status));
                    that.processing = false;
                }
            });
        },
        fileChange: function(attr, event) {
            var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;

            this.computedData[attr.name] = files[0].name;
            this.computedData[attr.file] = files[0];
        },
        showModal: function() {
            $('#' + this.id).modal('show');
        },
        closeModal: function() {
            $('#' + this.id).modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

            // this.$emit('submitted');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That should be a method, not a computed. Remember computeds always return a value and rarely take arguments. If you are not returning a value or you are passing an argument chances are you want to use a method.

Comment: Okay thanks - but how will I call the method in the component? That is what I am having difficulties with

Comment: It's difficult to decipher exactly what you are trying to do, maybe this JSFiddle will help: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/45o2d7tn/

Comment: I edited my post to include the component and template code. I have now changed my disableEmailText function to be under methods. I just am not sure how to link it to the commands component

Comment: Can't you just pass it through as a prop and disable the inputs based on that value.

Comment: @horcrux88 There is too much noise in the question to be able to answer it easily. You have hundred of lines of code that are not needed to ask this question. If, you build a minimal example of your problem it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @Gudradain thanks for the tip, I will in future try to limit code. I am still learning a lot (I'm quite new to this, I used to only work with CSS and HTML mostly and VB code). For now I managed to sort this issue, thanks to all who tried to help :)